# OpenModelica and JModelica deliver significantly different results

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica, pyfmi, pymodelica

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58219336/4999991), I'm trying to compare the results of the simulation between JModelica and OpenModelica. The Modelica file is identical to [the above-mentioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58219336/4999991) and the JModelica wrapper is the corrected version:

```py
#%%
from pymodelica import compile_fmu
from pyfmi import load_fmu
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#%%
model_name = 'friction1D.fricexample_1'
mofile = 'friction1D.mo'

#%%
fmu_name = compile_fmu(model_name, mofile)
sim = load_fmu(fmu_name)

#%%
opts = sim.simulate_options()
opts["ncp"] = 500
opts['CVode_options']['rtol'] = 1.0e-8
res = sim.simulate(final_time=10, options=opts)

#%%
time = res['time']
vel = res['v']
ffo = res['ffo']
sfo = res['sfo']

#%%
plt.plot(time, vel)
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Velocity (m/s)")
plt.show()

#%%
plt.plot(time, ffo, label="friction force")
plt.plot(time, sfo, label="shear force")
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Force (N)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

resulting in:

```
               
                      Fig.1 - Velocity versus time solved by JModelica.
```

and

```
               
           Fig.2 - Friction and shear force versus time solved by JModelica.
```

but if I set the simulation options in OpenModelica as:

```
                     
                    Fig.3 - Simulation options in OpenModelica.
```

which results in:

```
               
                   Fig.4 - Velocity versus time solved by OpenModelica.
```

and

```
               
        Fig.5 - Friction and shear force versus time solved by OpenModelica.
```

---

I would appreciate it if you could help me know why the results are so different and how I can achieve a similar simulation with these two different compilers.

**P.S.** posted a follow-up question [here on the OpenModelica forum](https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/2794-openmodelica-doesn-t-follow-the-discrete-logic-as-expected#p9401).

Answer (score 0):

First of all [the code, I had mentioned in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58219336/4999991) was wrong. In addition to some small issues which have been discussed [here](https://www.openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/2794-openmodelica-doesn-t-follow-the-discrete-logic-as-expected), one should use the `noEvent` function to be sure the conditions of an if-statement are compiled correctly (more info [here](https://www.openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/2795-bug-condition-of-an-if-statement-in-an-algorithm)). The correct version of the code is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58236860/4999991).

For JModelica to deliver similar results as OpenModelica I was instructed by [Christian Winther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093963/christian-winther) [here](https://github.com/modelon/PyFMI/issues/19#issuecomment-538510050) to play with the `opts["CVode_options"]["maxh"]` parameter which has a default value of `0`. I set the option to:

```
opts['CVode_options']['maxh'] = 0.01
```

and JModelica worked fine.